# Get error when installing react-native-popup-menu on react-native 0.59.3

Tags: react-native-popup-menu

I`m using react-native version 0.59.3, when i try installing react-native-popup-menu version 0.59.3 this error appear:

```
npm ERR! path c:\Users\...\node_modules\react-native
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'c:\Users\...\node_modules\react-native' -> 'c:\Users\...\node_modules\.react-native.DELETE'
```

Comment: Can you show some more info. What package are you trying to install? I assume the react-native-popup-menu, but which version etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just stopped running the project (or restart Pc) and run as administrator cmd then install react-native-popup-menu 0.15.6

It`s Work